# Checking IsDBNull using if statement

Tags: c#

The code only checks if condition, it avoids else condition, anything i'm doing wrong while using IsDBNull?. If the "if" condition fails, i want it to go to else condition.

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    if (!rd.IsDBNull(0))
    {
        //update table
    }
    else
    {
        //update table 
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your record even has any rows? If not, it might appear as if your `if` is failing, when in fact, it is never being called.

You can check this using the property `HasRows`.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement will always go to the `else` if the condition is false.

I cannot see your table so I can only speculate that for ever row read, the first column (usually a PK) is not null.

Remember, that loop will stop once there are no longer any rows to read. And what you are checking is if the first column is null (which, as you can see, it never is)

The if statement works and has always worked.

Comment: the code terminates at "while(rd.read())" when the value is null, how do i avoid that...I tried using if statement directly but is says invalid attempt to read when no data is present...

Comment: Came to learn that code was not returning a value, and used HasRows to solve it. Thanks..